# Склонение названия иностранного города

Tags: склонение

Припарковавшись в Бернхем(е)-Дипдейле, ранним июльским утром я отправился в путь.

Надо ли оставить окончание -е в первой части названия?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Название пишется раздельно и поэтому наиболее естественный вариант - склонять обе части.

Если у Вас есть нормативный источник, согласно которому требуется дефисное написание, там же по логике должно приводится и правило склонения. У меня таких словарей нет.

> а если нет словарей, то откуда такая уверенность, что написание
>   раздельное?

Если в двух словах, первая часть - название большого (относительно) города, а вторая - одной из деревушек вокруг него. Там их с десяток - и это обычное для Западной Европы дело. Вот, насколько могу судить, именно на такую ситуацию тенденция писать всё через дефис не распространяется. Аналога (в названиях) в русском нет, как объяснить по-другому, не знаю. Но могу и ошибаться, конечно.

Comment: Есть только данные турфирм, везде дефисное написание и в именительном падеже. Я засомневалась, вспомнив Баден-Баден.

Comment: @behemothus, а если нет словарей, то откуда такая уверенность, что написание раздельное? Обычно все-таки составные иностранные (неславянские, а иногда и славянские) названия пишут именно через дефис, обратные примеры единичны и имеет вполне рациональное объяснение ("Северный Рейн - Вестфалия").

Comment: Нашла и отдельное.

Comment: @Morkovkin *а если нет словарей, то откуда такая уверенность, что написание раздельное?* - хороший вопрос. )) Из гугло-карт.